# Eccentricity of two bodies in an unbound orbit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, binary-stars

There seems to be two definitions of an eccentricity of orbiting bodies, one for when it’s not bound and the other for when it is bound (Keplerian binary).
When the binary is bound there is a simple relation for the eccentricity but when the bodies are orbiting one another and are not bound, the definition of the eccentricity is given by:

$$e=(\text{apocenter}-\text{pericenter})/(\text{apocenter}+\text{pericenter})\tag{1}$$

1) for an unbound orbit we may not know what the peri and apo centre distances are (from obsevations).
2) suppose that these orbiting bodies undergo interactions but we still know the positions and velocities etc. How do I calculate the eccentricity (knowing the positions and velocities) of these types of unbound orbit systems?

Answer (score 1):

When you calculate the [orbital eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_eccentricity) in terms of energy and angular momentum, the same formula applies for circular orbits, elliptical orbits, parabolic trajectories, and hyperbolic trajectories. That formula is

$$e=\sqrt{1+\frac{2\epsilon h^2}{\mu^2}}.\tag1$$

Here $\epsilon$ is the [specific orbital energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_orbital_energy) (the energy --  kinetic plus potential -- divided by the [reduced mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_mass))

$$\epsilon=\frac{v^2}{2}-\frac{\mu}{r},\tag2$$

$h$ is the [specific angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_angular_momentum) (the angular momentum divided by the reduced mass)

$$\mathbf{h}=\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{v},\tag3$$

and $\mu$ is the "[standard gravitational parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter)"

$$\mu=G(m_1+m_2).$$

The vector $\mathbf{r}$ is the separation between the two masses and $\mathbf{v}$ is their relative velocity.

When reading the Wikipedia articles, you will notice that $\mu$ is unfortunately used in two different ways: to mean the reduced mass, and to mean the standard gravitational parameter.